# Phonegap restart app and preform function on reboot

Tags: ios, cordova

This is kind of a re-post of a my previuos question. However I did not word it correctly and I think everyone bailed on the question.

I have a phonegap app which has a native plugin to run location services and call a function in phonegap from the background. It works perfect.

What I want to do know is have it so when the phone reboots the app starts and location services start back up.

Google does this with their latitude app. Is it possible with phone gap?

Comment: Google probably doesn't use PhoneGap - they have a bunch of dedicated iOS devs that turn out amazing products.

Comment: I do realize that. But it has to be a native ability in the IOS. As I have built a phonegap plugin to constantly call JavaScript in phonegap from the background, I am wondering how I would do the same for when the phone reboots?